# SASS setColor Mixin

Tags: sass, compass-sass, mixins, compass

Why doesnt work my mixin in new compass version?

I want to set colors for navigationpoints. In the older compass verison everytihng works fine (0.12.6). I updated to the last Version and got the problemes.  This is my mixin and some parts of the sass files:

```
$basic: #f3f3f3;                      
$basicHO: #eeeeee;                     
$basicHL: #c3c3c3;



$classPrefix: color_;

$colorGroups: (
//class suffix      Normal      Hover        Hightlight

  default           $basic      $basicHo     $basicHL

);


@mixin setColors($classSelPrefix:"."){
  @each $group in $colorGroups {

    $colorClass: nth($group, 1);
    $colorNormal: nth($group, 2);
    $colorHover: nth($group, 3);
    $colorHighlight: nth($group, 4);
    $className: $classPrefix#{$colorClass};

    #{$classSelPrefix}#{$className} {
      @content;
    }

  }
}


 .exampleClass{
       @include setColors("& > .") {
          border-bottom-color: $colorNormal;

            a{
               border-color: $colorNormal;
               border-left: 3px solid $colorNormal;
            }
       }   
    }
```

Comment: ["Doesn't work" is never an appropriate explanation of the problem](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/).  What doesn't work?

Comment: You are right! The colors from the colorGroups arent set.